# What is best practice of 'ThemeProvider' in styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I wanna know where `<ThemeProvider/>` should be placed in React app.

I'd come up with two solutions about it.

1, `<ThemeProvider/>` should be used 'Just Once' in top-root component 
like `index.js` or `App.js` file created by 'create-react-app' tool.

2, `<ThemeProvicer/>` should be placed in 'Each root of React-component'
literally.

for clarification, I'll show you some example.
there is just two component, 'Red' and 'Blue' `<div>` tag.

1, `<ThemeProvider/>` used 'Just Once'

```
// In './red.js'
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"

const Red = styled.div`background: ${props => props.theme.mainColor}`

export default function RedDiv() {
    return (
        //NOT using ThemeProvider
        <Red />
    )
}
```

```
// In './blue.js'
......

const Blue = styled.div`background: ${props => props.theme.subColor}`

export default function BlueDiv() {
    return (
        <Blue />
    )
}
```

```
// In './App.js'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components"
import myTheme from "./myTheme
import Red from "./red"
import Blue from "./blue"

export default class App extends Component { 
    render() {
        return (
            //only used here just once
            <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
                <>
                    <Red />
                    <Blue />
                </>
            </ThemeProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

2, `<ThemeProvider/>` used 'Each root of React-component'

```
// In './red.js'
import React from 'react'
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components"

const Red = styled.div`background: ${props => props.theme.mainColor} `

export default function RedDiv() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
            <Red />
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

```
// In './blue.js'
......

const Blue = styled.div`background: ${props => props.theme.mainColor}`

export default function BlueDiv() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
            <Blue />
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

```
// In './App.js'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Red from "./red"
import Blue from "./blue"

export default class App extends Component { 
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                // <ThemeProvider/>  is not used
                <Red />
                <Blue />
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

there is maybe some typo on the code above, but I hope that this example will convey my idea clearly.

Comment: use it once, having multiple providers for the same context defeats the entire purpose of sharing a singleton context throughout your app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use it only once, inside `index.js`.

Also a good place to add some global styles, if you need them. I use them for `resetCSS` (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and some `baseCSS` rules like `box-sizing` etc.

**index.js**

```
import { createGlobalStyle, ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import theme from './styles/theme';
import resetCSS from './styles/resetCSS';
import baseCSS from './styles/baseCSS';
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  ${resetCSS}
  ${baseCSS}
`;

React.DOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <GlobalStyle/>
    <Router>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <App/>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  </React.Fragment>
  ,document.getElementById('root')
);
```